# Update link text with content from XML document

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

For each link, e.g.

```
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/item=78363">http://www.wowhead.com/item=78363</a>
```

I'd like to retrieve the ID at the end of the URL in the `href` attribute. For example, `78363`, as seen above. Using this ID, I'd like to retrieve an XML page and get data from it based on the ID. The URL of the XML document is the same as the link to the item, but ending with `&xml`, so:

```
http://www.wowhead.com/item=78363&xml
```

From XML page I need the value inside the `CDATA` section seen below:

```
<name>
<![CDATA[Vagaries of Time]]>
</name>
```

That is, "Vagaries of Time". Then I need to insert the name inside the tag:

```
<a href="http://www.wowhead.com/item=78363">Vagaries of Time</a>
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: AGH! MY EYES! Please keep formatting to standard levels, thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry, my English is not good, anyway thank you for editing.

Comment: Or some other idea? Maybe between the xml page and script paste a php file with the code, then will obtain data at the request of the script? `/get_xml.php?id=78363`? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the links based on a regular expression, send an Ajax request, parse the text using regular expressions, and done.

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if(/item=\d+$/.test(this.href)) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href + '&xml',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data) {
                $this.text(/<!\[CDATA\[([^\]]+)/.exec(data)[1]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You'll most likely want to add some error-checking, of course. Also, if your XML document is more complex than the example you posted, consider parsing using the native XML capabilities instead - I just used a regular expression for simplicity there.

Comment: XML page is live: http://www.wowhead.com/item=78363&xml (sites from which we obtain the data is not mine).

Comment: And on this XML page are more options CDATA :-/

Comment: @Edoras: Okay, you'll need to proxy the page with your own server; the cross-origin policy won't let you send requests to it through Ajax directly. As for the other CDATA, the one you need is the first one, so no problem.

Comment: Oh, if I understand - when XML is not my page, and I do not know the proxy server, so it does not work? :(